# Problems with Parallel and Rcpp Armadillo: Possible variable corruption between cluster workers

Tags: r, parallel-processing, rcpp, rcpparmadillo

I am having some problems with using Rcpp (and Rcpp Armadillo) with the parallel package, and I am getting incorrect results depending on the number of cores I use for computation.

I have a function `compute_indices` which computes 3 set of indices for each observation in my data. It does this by first creating a (FORK) cluster using `parallel::makeCluster` depending on the number of cores I specify. It then splits my data into equal parts and applies (using `parallel::parLapply`) a function `meancorlsm` on each part using the cluster object I created earlier. Now `meancorlsm` is basically a wrapper around a function (called `covArmadilloMclsmNormal`) I wrote in Rcpp and Rcpp Armadillo as I am trying to speed up computation. However, I have another version of this function written entirely in R (called `meancorlsR`) which I use to test correctness of the RccpArmadillo version.

Now if I run `compute_indices` with the `meancorlsm` (this I do by first using `sourceCpp()` to make `covArmadilloMclsmNormal` available in the global environment), I get partially correct answers depending on the number of cores I tell `compute_indices` to use. Specifically, if I use 4 cores, the first 1/4 of the computed indices are correct, if I use 2 cores, the first 1/2 of my results are correct, and if I use a single core, all my results are correct. I check the correctness of the results using the answer produced by using the R version of the `meancorlsm` (`meancorlsR` as stated earlier). Since I am getting correct results when I use a single core, I feel the RcppArmadillo function is correct and that possibly, the different threads/workers of the cluster are interfering with each other during the computation, hence the reason I get this strange behaviour.

Below is `compute_indices`:

```
compute_indices <- function(dt, nr = ncol(dt), n_core = 4){ 
  par_cluster <- makeCluster(n_core, type = "FORK")
  # compute the column splits/partition for parallel processing
  splits <- parallel:::splitList(1:nr, n_core)
  # compute auxiliar support data
  data_means <- colMeans(dt, na.rm = T)
  data_vars <- apply(dt, MARGIN =  2, var)
  data_sds <- apply(dt, 2, sd)
  # compute Outliers using parapply
  vectors <- do.call(rbind, parLapply(par_cluster, splits,
                                      meancorlsm, dt, data_means,
                                      data_vars, data_sds))
  stopCluster(par_cluster)
  vectors
}
```

and `meancorlsm`

```
meancorlsm<- function(i, mtx, means, vars, sds){
  pre_outl <- covArmadilloMclsmNormal(dti = mtx[,i], dt = mtx,
                                      dtmeans = means, dtvars = vars,
                                      dtsds = sds)
  colnames(pre_outl) <- c("sh", "mg", "ap")
  pre_outl
}
```

with the `covArmadilloMclsmNormal` Rcpp function:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
using namespace Rcpp;


//[[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
// [[Rcpp::export]]

arma::mat covArmadilloMclsmNormal(arma::mat dti, arma::mat dt,
                     arma::vec dtmeans, arma::vec dtvars,
                     arma::vec dtsds){
  arma::mat out(dt.n_cols, dti.n_cols);
  out = arma::cov(dt, dti);
  int n = out.n_rows;
  int p = out.n_cols;
  //declare matrices to hold result
  arma::vec temp(n);
  arma::mat preout(3,p);
  for(int i = 0; i<p ; ++i){
    temp = out.col(i)/dtvars;
    preout(0,i) = arma::mean((out.col(i)/dtsds))/dtsds(i); 
    preout(1, i) = dtmeans(i) - arma::mean(temp % dtmeans);
    preout(2, i) = arma::mean(temp); 
  }

  return preout.t();
}
```

Now here is the R version of `meancorlsm` which I use for testing:

```
meancorlsR <- function(i, mtx, means, vars, sds){
  pre_outl <- apply(cov(mtx, mtx[,i], use = "pairwise.complete.obs"), 2,
                    function(col){
                      tmp <- col/vars
                      c("sh" = mean(col/sds, na.rm = T), 
                        "mg" = mean(tmp * means, na.rm = T), 
                        "ap" = mean(tmp, na.rm = T)) 
                    })
  pre_outl[1,] <- pre_outl[1,]/sds[i] 
  pre_outl[2,] <- means[i] - pre_outl[2,] 
  t(pre_outl)
}
```

You can replace `meancorlsm` function with `meancorlsR` in the `compute_indices` function and it will work (for testing). For immediate reproducibility however, I provide it here as `compute_indicesR`.

```
compute_indicesR <- function(dt, nr = ncol(dt), n_core = 4){ 
  par_cluster <- makeCluster(n_core, type = "FORK")
  # compute the column splits/partition for parallel processing
  splits <- parallel:::splitList(1:nr, n_core)
  # compute auxiliar support data
  data_means <- colMeans(dt, na.rm = T)
  data_vars <- apply(dt, MARGIN =  2, var)
  data_sds <- apply(dt, 2, sd)
  # compute using parapply
  vectors <- do.call(rbind, parLapply(par_cluster, splits,
                                      meancorlsR, dt, data_means, 
                                      data_vars, data_sds))
  stopCluster(par_cluster)
  vectors
}
```

Finally here is a minimal example to run:

```
library(Rcpp)
library(parallel)
# use this to source the Rcpp function from a file
# to make the covArmadilloMclsmNormal function available
sourceCpp("covArmadilloMclsmNormal.cpp")

data("attitude") # available in datasets in base R
dt <- t(as.matrix(attitude[1:10,])) #select first 10 row 

indices_rcpp4 <- compute_indices(dt) # using 4 cores
indices_rcpp2 <- compute_indices(dt, n_core = 2) # using 2 cores
indices_rcpp1 <- compute_indices(dt, n_core = 1) # 1 core
# using the R version
# already replaced the meancorlsm function to meancorlsR here  
indices_R <- compute_indicesR(dt) # R version
```

I expect all the output to match the one produced by the R version regardless of the number of cores I specify. However, they are different. Here is the result I get with the R version:

```
"           sh               mg               ap 
1   0.634272567307155 -7.09315427645087   0.992492531586726
2   0.868144125333511  22.3206363514708   0.622504642756242
3   0.819231480417289  24.8027625928423   0.756088388472384
4   0.830462006956641 -6.26663378557611   1.03847748215856
5   0.836182582923674  15.0558414918816   0.901413435882058
6   0.648813304451793  23.4689784056255   0.40175151333289
7   0.839409670144446  3.73900558549848   0.883655665107456
8   0.781070895796188  13.1775081516076   0.810306856575333
9   0.772967959938828  2.24023877077873   1.1146249477264
10  0.826849986442202  3.31330282673472   0.910527502047015"
```

The result I got with the Rcpp version using 2 cores is

```
"           sh               mg               ap 
1   0.634272567307155 -7.09315427645086   0.992492531586726
2   0.868144125333511  22.3206363514708   0.622504642756242
3   0.819231480417289  24.8027625928424   0.756088388472384
4   0.830462006956641 -6.26663378557612   1.03847748215856
5   0.836182582923674  15.0558414918816   0.901413435882058
6   0.231943043232274  28.1832641199112   0.40175151333289
7   1.20839881621289   7.02471987121276   0.883655665107456
8   0.865212462148289  21.7489367230362   0.810306856575333
9   0.853048693647409  -10.474046943507   1.1146249477264
10  0.857055188335614  14.599017112449    0.910527502047015"
```

while for the Rccp version using 4 cores:

```
"           sh               mg               ap 
1   0.634272567307155 -7.09315427645086   0.992492531586726
2   0.868144125333511  22.3206363514708   0.622504642756242
3   0.819231480417289  24.8027625928424   0.756088388472384
4   0.648794650804865 -10.2666337855761   1.03847748215856
5   1.25119408317776   5.48441292045304   0.901413435882058
6   0.231943043232274  28.1832641199112   0.40175151333289
7   1.20839881621289   7.02471987121276   0.883655665107456
8   0.487272877566209  3.60607958017906   0.810306856575333
9   1.50139103326263  -6.75976122922128   1.1146249477264
10  1.01076542369015   15.4561599695919   0.910527502047015"
```

The Rccp version using a single core produced the same answer as the R version which is the correct result. Also interesting is that the `ap` column of the answer remained the same no matter the number of cores I used while the `sh` and the `mg` column changes.

Finally, my platform is Ubuntu 16.04. Seems `FORK` clusters doesn't work on Windows so you might not be able to reproduce this result. However, I got the same behaviour even with `PSOCK` cluster (in which case I used `clusterEvalQ()` to source the necessary Cpp functions to make them available to the workers). Any help or insight as to what I am doing wrong is much appreciated.

Comment: Hi Segun -- that is a long question but in general be aware that parallel work is best done on independent data chunks as R is very clearly not multithread safe.  Maybe take a look at the RcppParallel documentation and its examples -- and their use of `RMatrix` and `RVector`.

Comment: I don't have all the math in my head right now, but based on `arma::cov`'s documentation, shouldn't you be splitting by row? So using `nr = nrow(dt)` and then `mtx[i,]`.

Comment: Probably `mtx[i, , drop = FALSE]` to be sure.

Comment: Hi Alexis, the whole function is written in such a way that the data is in a long format, i.e I transposed the data before parsing into my function. Hence the rows of the data are actually gotten by the referencing the columns in the function.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Thanks I will look into RcppParallel. Do you think maybe if I built a package things could work better? Maybe the fact that I am using sourceCpp to feed the worker could be a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind my comments, I misinterpreted Armadillo's documentation.

Your C++ code is indexing the helper `dtmeans` and `dtsds` vectors with `i`,
but `i` always starts at zero for each parallel instance,
so you need to pass an offset indicating how many columns were skipped:

```
//[[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

//[[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat covArmadilloMclsmNormal(arma::mat dti, arma::mat dt, int offset,
                                  arma::vec dtmeans, arma::vec dtvars, arma::vec dtsds)
{
  arma::mat out = arma::cov(dt, dti);
  size_t p = out.n_cols;

  arma::mat preout(p,3);
  for (int i = 0; i < p; ++i) {
    arma::vec temp = out.col(i) / dtvars;
    preout(i,0) = arma::mean((out.col(i) / dtsds)) / dtsds(i + offset); 
    preout(i,1) = dtmeans(i + offset) - arma::mean(temp % dtmeans);
    preout(i,2) = arma::mean(temp); 
  }

  return preout;
}
```

So accordingly:

```
meancorlsm <- function(i, mtx, means, vars, sds){
  pre_outl <- covArmadilloMclsmNormal(dti = mtx[,i, drop = FALSE], dt = mtx, offset = min(i) - 1L,
                                      dtmeans = means, dtvars = vars,
                                      dtsds = sds)
  colnames(pre_outl) <- c("sh", "mg", "ap")
  pre_outl
}
```

You can even corroborate it sequentially:

```
data("attitude") # available in datasets in base R
dt <- t(as.matrix(attitude[1:10,])) #select first 10 row 

# compute the column splits/partition for parallel processing
splits <- parallel:::splitList(1:ncol(dt), 2)

# compute auxiliary support data
data_means <- colMeans(dt, na.rm = T)
data_vars <- apply(dt, MARGIN =  2, var)
data_sds <- apply(dt, 2, sd)

do.call(rbind, lapply(splits,
                      meancorlsm, dt, data_means,
                      data_vars, data_sds))
             sh        mg        ap
 [1,] 0.6342726 -7.093154 0.9924925
 [2,] 0.8681441 22.320636 0.6225046
 [3,] 0.8192315 24.802763 0.7560884
 [4,] 0.8304620 -6.266634 1.0384775
 [5,] 0.8361826 15.055841 0.9014134
 [6,] 0.6488133 23.468978 0.4017515
 [7,] 0.8394097  3.739006 0.8836557
 [8,] 0.7810709 13.177508 0.8103069
 [9,] 0.7729680  2.240239 1.1146249
[10,] 0.8268500  3.313303 0.9105275
```

BTW, I think pre-allocating matrices in the C++ code is of no use if you'll simply overwrite them with `=`.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for this. Can you please clarify the last suggestion about preallocating matrices. Sorry but this is my first time using Rcpp and armadillo so I am not familiar about memory management. How can I make it more efficient? where I am preallocating a matrix that is not necessary. Thanks

Comment: @SegunOjo Like when you first define `arma::mat out(dt.n_cols, dti.n_cols)` but immediately overwrite it with `out = arma::cov(dt, dti)`; the former allocates memory that is never used, because `out` ends up holding the memory allocated by `arma::cov` internally. It's more of a C++ thing, not `Rcpp`; search for copy and move semantics.